# What does multifrequency volatility mean?

Tags: volatility

I came across the term "multifrequency volatility" while reading the book "Multifractal Volatility: Theory, Forecasting, and Pricing" (2008) by Calvet and Fisher. Can anyone help me understand what does this term mean?